# how to read sh files on Ubuntu built in Windows 10 developer mode

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I use bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 to open a sh file I downloaded. But when I put the sh files in my directory in Ubuntu I can't see them. I can see them and my other files in Windows directory but not in Ubuntu.

Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 is a built in feature in Windows 10. It can be used in developer mode. It is not CMD or command prompt or whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You home directory in bash is

```
c:\Users\<Windows User>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<linux_username>\
```

**UPDATE:**

sorry, I misread your question, you have a problem seeing these files from bash, when they are saved by Windows. I'm not sure how exactly this works regarding home folder, but you can access any Windows files from bash using filesystem in /mnt/

So the above would be `/mnt/c/Users/<Windows User>/AppData/....` etc

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is more information about the problem - https://superuser.com/questions/1083962/windows-linux-subsystem-accessing-files-outside-of-ubuntu
Basically, confirming what I said above - you have to use /mnt/

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mind telling me how do you search and get the solution? I used google but didn't find things really related and useful.

Comment: @jessie I'm not sure if I can answer this. I already knew about /mnt/ and home folder location, so only needed to try this on my computer to verify. I was actually surprised to find that files changed in Windows are not visible from Linux subsystem. The second update and the link to superuser.com was indeed just a result of using Google.

Comment: I don't know why.Before I searched a link and used that mnt directory but didn't find those downloaded files. But this time they are showed.  And I'm sure I didn't use the wring directory. Anyway thanks!