# How to access Google Drive Folder from Ubuntu App in Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, google-drive-api, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu app inside of windows 10. I can access most of windows files using bash. The windows documents are inside of `/mnt/c`. Thats ok.

I can access "Google Drive" folder in Command Prompt (cmd.exe) with entering `G:` command in Windows 10. (Google Drive Commercial, drive file stream) It is also ok. My question is

Is there any way to access "Google Drive" folder using bash?

Attempt 1:

I made a shortcut of "Google Drive" folder in Windows' desktop. I open the bash, and write `cd /mnt/c/Users/Taygun Bulmus/Desktop`. But it is not a directory.

Related questions:

[how to read sh files on Ubuntu built in Windows 10 developer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882764/how-to-read-sh-files-on-ubuntu-built-in-windows-10-developer-mode),

[Windows Linux Subsystem - Accessing Files outside of Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/1083962/windows-linux-subsystem-accessing-files-outside-of-ubuntu)

**EDIT 1:**

It is still open issue for wsl community (17/03/2020):

[Mount Google Drive File System to WSL #2999](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2999)

Answer (score 4):

I don't if you're experiencing the exact same issue, but I know my mount works properly for a while and then doesn't work anymore from the WSL only. An `ls` command revealed this beauty:
[Cannot add an embedded picture yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UptKl.png)

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207755/google-drive-virtual-drive-mount-in-wsl2) I remounted the drive and everything seems to work now :) the command was:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

Comment: thank you! 
My scenario was that Drive would work for a while, then if I closed WSL and put the computer to sleep, then tried to open WSL again and access my drive, it would give the error "'/mnt/g': Invalid argument" when trying to cd into Drive.

Comment: This works for mounting, but everything is owned by root. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

This works now:

On WSL 2, Windows 20H2 (set to German), Google Drive Version 47.0.19.0

```
windows@DESKTOP-I608RI4:/mnt/g/Meine Ablage/Data$ echo hello > hello-cr.txt
windows@DESKTOP-I608RI4:/mnt/g/Meine Ablage/Data$ ls
```

Comment: Yep, I do the same, however when some time passes (I talk about days), for some reason that I do not know, Google drive restarts or updates (or so I think) which closes the link between WSL and Google drive, and I must restart WSL, do you think of some way to reestablish the link without restarting WSL?

Comment: Additionally, I have tried to create a soft link from Windows but this is inherited to Ubuntu then the same if it is restarted (or whatever) GD it is dismantled in WSL and the link stops working in WSL

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not any solution for google drive for commercial use: "Drive File Stream" ([see this REF](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2999)). For personal use, you can specify a folder that you can access from bash.

Open bash,

```
cd /mnt/c/[%Your Synced Google Drive Folder%]
```

Answer (score 0):

For access folder use command: `cd /mnt/<drive>/address_folder'`

Answer (score 0):

go to `C:\Windows\System32` and create a shortcut of `wsl.exe`. Then you can change the "start in" property of the shortcut to your drive path and voilà.