# Google drive - virtual drive mount in WSL2

Tags: google-drive-api, wsl-2

does anybody know if i could mount the Google drive (virtual drive) in a win10 system, in wsl2?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

The first time you do it, run `sudo mkdir /mnt/g` first.

Comment: Is there a way to add this to the fstab?